# How to call an extension method to remove an item from an array

Tags: c#

In a very old code base I have inherited, there is a method with this signature

```
public static void Remove<TSource>(this ICollection<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
```

And I am trying to call this method on an array. The array is named Items and is a property of a section

```
section.Items.Remove(// what goes here?)
```

Items is an array of Products.

For clarity, here is the Remove method

```
    public static void Remove<TSource>(this ICollection<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        var items = source.ToArray();
        for (var index = items.Length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            var item = items[index];
            if (predicate.Invoke(item))
            {
                source.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot remove items from an array, by the way.

Comment: Just call it Collection instead of Array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass in a lambda to filter what gets removed (if the name of the parameter and function are logical)

For example:

```
section.Items.Remove(p => p.Id == 1);
```

This should remove all items with an Id of 1 (Assuming such a property exists)

**Note** It's hard to say exactly what the method does since arrays can't be resized. The method takes an `ICollection` which can have items remove but you say you pass in an array. The array would give an error when  `ICollection.Remove` is invoked.

**Edit**

Since you posted the code of the method, I can say with certainty that the method would fail for an array. It would work for other `ICollection` implementations (`List` for example).

Just to point out I would not really use this method to remove a lot of elements form a large collections, as the method will iterate the collection again to  remove each object. Not to mention it will allocate a new array to copy the whole collection (perf nightmare for large collections).

Comment: I was mistaken, it is a collection that is passed in. This helped me a lot